# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: javascript

File structure:

[image]

app.js

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("app", ["common.services", "ngRoute", "ngResource"])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        //.when('/', {
        //    controller: 'mainController',
        //    templateUrl: 'app/linkPages/home.html'
        //})

        // route for the about page
        //.when('/about', {
        //    controller: 'aboutController',
        //    templateUrl: 'app/linkPages/about.html'
        //})

        // route for the contact page
        //.when('/contact', {
        //    controller: 'contactController',
        //    templateUrl: 'app/linkPages/contact.html'
        //})

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'AgencyListCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/agencies/agencyListView.html'
        })

        //.when('/agencyEditView', {
        //    controller: 'AgencyEditCtrl',
        //    templateUrl: 'app/agencies/agencyEditView.html'
        //});

    });

    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'This is the Main controller page';
    });

    app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'This is the about controller page';
    });

    app.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'This is the contact controller page';
    });

}());
```

common.services.js

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services",
                    ["ngResource"])//common.services

        .constant("appSettings",
        {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:53403/" // will replace production server url 
        });
}());
```

agencyResource.js

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app")//common.services
        .factory("agencyResource"
                ["ngResource", "$resource",
                 "appSettings",
                    agencyResource])

    function agencyResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/v1/agencies/:id", null,
            {
                'update': { method: 'PUT' },
            });
    }

}());
```

agencyListCtrl.js

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("AgencyListCtrl",
                    ["agencyResource",
                     AgencyListCtrl]);

    function AgencyListCtrl(agencyResource) {
        var vm = this;

        //agencyResource.query({ $filter: "contains(Abbr,'IOT')" },
        //    function (data) {
        //        vm.agencies = data;

        //        console.log(result);
            //})

        agencyResource.query({},
            function (data) {
                vm.agencies = data;

        console.log(result);
    })

}
}());
```

> ERROR:
>
> HTML1300: Navigation occurred. index.html Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   Unknown provider: agencyResourceProvider <- agencyResource <-
>   AgencyListCtrl
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/unpr?p0=agencyResourceProvider%20%3C-%20agencyResource%20%3C-%20AgencyListCtrl
>          at Anonymous function (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4554:13)
>          at getService (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4707:11)
>          at Anonymous function (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4559:13)
>          at getService (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4707:11)
>          at injectionArgs (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4731:9)
>          at instantiate (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:4774:7)
>          at $controller (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:10533:7)
>          at link (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular-route.js:1056:9)
>          at Anonymous function (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:1258:11)
>          at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:61924/Scripts/angular.js:10095:9)

I am not sure weather I have injected everything right here? Any help would be appreciated. This is my first angular app so I am a little green. Stack Overflow is telling me I have to type more details but the code post are pretty self explanatory. I

Comment: Check in index.html if you are importing agencyResource.js before agencyListCtrl.js

Comment: I am a bit curios on your agencyResource resource declaration. 
You are injecting '"ngResource", "$resource", "appSettings"', but your parameters are 'agencyResource($resource, appSettings)'. Could be a broblem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was declaring ngResource in the agencyResource.js file. It should look like this. MY BAD.

agencyResource.js

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services")//common.services
        .factory("agencyResource",
                [
                 "$resource",
                 "appSettings",
                  agencyResource
                ])

    function agencyResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/v1/agencies/:id", null,
            {
                'update': { method: 'PUT' },
            });
    }

}());
```